# GDAL warp error in Python

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to create a mosaic in GDAL using Python. When I run the code i get the following error message:

> TypeError: object of wrong GDALDatasetShadow

The code is the following:

```
def gdal_merger(source, dest):
    for doy_dirs in os.listdir(source):
        print(f"Processing: {doy_dirs}")
        # output_name = str(os.path.join(dest,f"{doy_dirs}.tif"))
        doy_dir_source = [product for product in os.listdir(os.path.join(source,doy_dirs))]
        process = gdal.Warp(str(os.path.join(dest,f"{doy_dirs}.tif")), doy_dir_source, format = "GTiff")
        process = None
```

Comment: os listdir also list directories, have you thought of that

Comment: Yes, because I need to merge all tifs in each subdirectory

Comment: It would be a good idea to print the results of `os.path.join(dest,f"{doy_dirs}.tif")` and `doy_dir_source` to make sure there's nothing funny there, because `os.listdir()` will give you everything in that directory. You will probably have more control with Python's `glob` package. Once you have printed out one iteration of the `doy_dirs` loop, try running `gdal_warp` from the command line with the same parameters to see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using call of the merge function directly from the code of my Python's GDAL.

```
python gdal_merge.py {parameters}
```